Is there any alternative way to matrix strategy in github action #35456
We are using Terraform as IaC in our organization. I am facing an issue where we need to deploy the same set of resources for multiple groups and divisions. For example, I have 'ABC' as a group, which contains divisions 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. I need to deploy to all divisions at the same time. Currently, I am using GitHub Actions with a feature called matrix, but it creates separate jobs and the billing cost is high. I want to reduce the cost of running GitHub Actions.
          group=${GROUPS}
          divisions=${DIVISIONS}

          divisions=${divisions#\[}
          divisions=${divisions%\]}
          IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$divisions"

          task () {
            
              echo "Starting task for the $2 division"

              cd ./infra/terraform/scheduleQueryStack
              terraform workspace select -or-create "${1}_${2}_schedulequery_stack_test"

              export TF_VAR_environment=${{ inputs.Stage }}
              export TF_VAR_group=$1
              export TF_VAR_region=${{ inputs.Region }}
              export TF_VAR_division=$2

              terraform apply --auto-approve

              echo "Task for the $2 division completed"             
          }
          
          # Array to store PIDs of background tasks
          pids=()
          # Max number of background tasks can be run at a time is 4.
          max_concurrent=4

          remove_empty_pids() {
            local new_pids=()
            for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
              if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
                new_pids+=("$pid")
              fi
            done
            pids=("${new_pids[@]}")
          }

          # Function to list all running background tasks
          list_background_tasks() {
            echo "PIDs of background running tasks. ${pids[@]}"
            echo "Current total number of PIDs: ${#pids[@]}"
            for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
              if kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; then
                echo "Task with PID $pid is running"
              else
                echo "Task with PID $pid has completed"
                # If a background task has completed, it will be removed from the array
                pids=("${pids[@]/$pid}")
                remove_empty_pids
                echo "$pid PID removed from the PIDs array"
              fi
            done
          }

          # Run tasks in parallel using background processes and save their PIDs
          for division in "${array[@]}"; do

            # Check if the number of background tasks has reached the limit
            while [ ${#pids[@]} -ge $max_concurrent ]; do
              list_background_tasks
              sleep 60
              echo "Sleeping for a minute to complete the background tasks"
            done

            # Run the task in the background
            task "$group" "$division" &
            # Get the process ID of the task and add PID of background tasks to array. 
            pids+=($!)
          done

          # Function to wait for all background tasks to complete
          wait_for_background_tasks() {
            for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
              wait "$pid"
            done
          }

          # Wait for all background tasks to complete
          wait_for_background_tasks

          echo "All tasks completed"```


Matrix is the only way to create dynamic workflows natively. Matrix value do not need to be known when a workflow is created. They can be passed into the workflow as inputs.
However, when you use a matrix, every job in a matrix runs on a separate runner in parallel. As a result, the overall workflow will complete faster but you will incur runner start-up/tear-down costs. Every runner will have to do a checkout and setup.
The only other way is to do it yourself in bash:
for division in 1 2 3 4 5; do
  terraform ... $division
done

or in a custom composite action that will hide this loop.
In this case, you will run all deployments on a single runner sequentially with a single checkout and setup.

Thank you for your response. Just looping doesn't help me because it will increase deployment time, as each task will be taken up only after the previous one completes.

If you want to parallelise, you will have  to run each terraform as a background process using &. You would need to get PID for each process and use wait $PID after the loop.

I have tested background processes as mentioned in the updated post. However, when I run the terraform plan command, it indicates that changes are needed in the resources. This is a problem because if we apply these changes, existing resources may be deleted and recreated, leading to data loss.

Using self-hosted runners may be another option if you have a Kubernetes cluster. However, it means extra dev time.
